# How to run tezos node in private mode using docker images?

Tags: baking, security, private-mode, baker, docker

I already have my node up and running using **docker images** with default configuration, so how can i change it to run in private node so that I can run few sentry nodes connected to public network and then connect my private node to sentry nodes to avoid exposing my baker node publically.

I already know [this](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/introduction/various.html#private-node), so I need a solution using docker images.

Answer (score 6):

When you launch the docker node with `./mainnet.sh start`, you can add extra arguments such as `--private-mode --peer AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:PORT` (you probably need to specify `--peer` to connect your private node to your public node).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I already have my node running as public node. Now if i stop the node container and then start it with private node flag, will there be any side effect to my current setup (like connection failure with previously connected node or some other unexpected error) OR i should be good to go?

Comment: It should work, but you will probably notice some connections being rejected. That's not a problem, disregard them.

Comment: I think there is some syntax error in above configuration options. it should be --peer=AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:PORT . An = instead of <space>

Comment: I used this command ./mainnet.sh start --private-mode --no-bootstrap-peers --bootstrap-threshold=1 --connections 1 --peer <public-node-ip>     But all i get is incoming connections rejected but my node is not getting connected to my public node.

Comment: Did you also specify the port, ie ˋ—peer host:port` ? Note that, if the public node is already full, it will reject your connection.

Comment: No i did not specify the port. Do i need to specify the port 8732? And how do i know that my public node is already full or not? And what to do if my public node is full?

Comment: @SachinTomar I'm having the same problem. My private node not connecting to my public node. And my private node getting "[private node] incoming connection from untrused peer rejected!" Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Svante Yes i first add my private node IP and public node IP to each other server using command sudo ./mainnet.sh admin-client trust address <IP Address>:9732    and as mentioned by lefessan i added --peer option in my start docker command  ./mainnet.sh start --private-mode --peer <public-IP>:9732   You can ignore the "incoming connection from untrusted peer rejected" messages